# Why I am seeing small voltage in the voltage display from detector?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, voltage-measurement, voltage-detector

I am using this [detector](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=1295) to detect the brightness of an LED (powered and controlled by controller). When I use [this multimeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000OCFFMW) to measure the detector output, I see the range of detector from 0-12.13V. On the other hand, when I use the [voltage display](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CJRE1PM), I see very low range of 0-0.4V. The connection diagram with detector and display is as below.

Why am I seeing such a low range in the display and how can I increase the range?

[image]

Comment: Did you use a terminating resistor on the output of the detector as recommended in the description?

Comment: When I connected 50 ohm terminating resistor from BNC cable negative to bnc cable ground, display does not show anything at all. On the other hand, if I connect 50 ohm in series with BNC cable, I see output but in the same range of 0-.4 V

Answer (score 2):

Detectors like the one you have chosen have a current rather than a voltage output, and the current may be very low, in the nanoamp or picoamp range.  Therefore a transconductance amplifier is used for these signals.  Your high-quality Fluke multimeter has a high input impedance, high enough for the small current to cause a larger voltage across the meter leads.  Your voltage display likely does not have such a high impedance, so the resulting voltage will be proportionally lower.  If you place a 50-Ohm load on the circuit, the small current will not produce a measurable voltage with your equipment.